I'm looking for the title of a book about a group of dream warriors who fight a "demon" with psychic abilities that hides in peoples dreams
I read a book in the early- to mid-eighties that I have not been able to recall the title to.  The story was set in roughly the present day.  A small group of people were able to enter the dream world by drawing a pentagram in the air, which had a silvery outline when drawn, then pulled the pieces of the pentagram apart until they were able to climb through the pentagram like a doorway into the dream world. While inside the dream world they each had a special talent.  For example, one was a builder and could create things (like staircases) out of the elements in the air. The group of dream warriors ends up fighting a "demon", which turned out to be a prehistoric creature that developed psychic abilities that it used to hide inside the minds of other creatures.

You are looking for Death Dream, a 1988 novel by Graham Masterton. This novel is the second volume in Masterton's "Night Warrior" series, which starts with Night Warriors. The series continues after Death Dream with Night Plague, Night Wars, and The Ninth Nightmare. In the plot of Death Dream, Masterton's night warriors come to the aid of a young boy who plays unwilling host to the prehistoric imagination monster. The creature projects itself from its host's dreams to tear its victims apart with its scythe-like claws.


Did the previous book "Night Warriors" from 1986 also feature a team of people fighting a monster with long claws in dreams? The synopsis reminds me of the movie Nightmare on Elm Street 3: Dream Warriors from 1987, I wonder if there's any chance either was an inspiration for the other.

@Hypnosifl I've only read "Death Dream" from the series. The synopsis for "Night Warriors" indicates similarities between the two novels, although the claws are not mentioned. There are similarities between the third "Nightmare" film and the novel.
